# Craft 3 beta - User group total

Tags: users, search, craft3

I have tried to find the new way get the total in a user group in php (plugin), but not having much luck... Please help
Assume it starts with Craft::$app->users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ActiveRecord` from [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html)

```
$userGroupId = 1 // insert your usergroup Id here
$users = User::find()->groupId($userGroupId)->all();
```

Or via handle

```
$userGroup = Craft::$app->userGroups->getGroupByHandle('handle');
$users = User::find()->group($userGroup)->all();
```

If you mean the number of users in a group with total you just have to do `count()` instead of `all()`

To get the users of each group you can do

```
foreach(Craft::$app->userGroups->getAllGroups() as $userGroup){
    $users = User::find()->group($userGroup)->all();
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you for the thorough answer